# Representation of $\mathcal{H}$ as $\mathbb{C}^{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be an inner-product space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $A$ be a linear operator on $\mathcal{H}$ such that $A^{2} = 0$ nd $A^{*}A+AA^{*} = \text{Id}$, where $\text{Id}$ is the identity matrix and $A^{*}$ is the adjoint of $A$.

I proved that $\mathcal{H} = \text{Ker}A\oplus \text{Ker}A^{*}$ and that $\text{Ker}A$ and $\text{Ker}A^{*}$ are both orthogonal sets. Now I am trying to prove that $\mathcal{H}$ can be thought as $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ in which case $A$ and $A^{*}$ both have representations s $2\times 2$ complex matrices.

My thoughts are the following. Every $\varphi \in \mathcal{H}$ can be decomposed as $\varphi = \varphi_{1}+\varphi_{2}$ where $\varphi_{1}\in \text{Ker}A$ and $\varphi_{2} \in \text{Ker}A^{*}$. Hence, it is natural to think of $\mathcal{H}$ as the set of column vectors:
$$\varphi =\begin{pmatrix}
\varphi_{1} \\
\varphi_{2}
\end{pmatrix}$$
In this representation, $A$ and $A^{*}$ have representations as $2\times 2$ matrices, but I don't know if this is the right way of thinking about $\mathcal{H}$. This is because each $\varphi_{1}$ and $\varphi_{2}$ are vectors, so my representation does not look like $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ to me apart from the fact that $A$ and $A^{*}$ are $2\times 2$ matrices. For instance, what are the vectors $\varphi \in \mathcal{H}$ equivalent to $\binom{0}{1}$ or $\binom{1}{0}$ in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$? Is there a better way of seing $\mathcal{H}$ as $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case you have $A(\ker A)=\{0\}$. This makes you write
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 0& a\\0&b\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Combined with $A^*(\ker A^*)=\{0\}$, we get
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 0& a\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
This agrees with $A^2=0$. And
$$
I=A^*A+AA^*=\begin{bmatrix} aa^*&0\\0& a^*a\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So $a$, which is an operator $\ker A^*\to\ker A$, is a unitary. This allows us to think of $H$ as $H_0\oplus H_0$, and of $A$ as $\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$. More concretely, if $H_0=\ker A$ and $U:H\to H_0\oplus H_0$ is $U(\varphi_1+\varphi_2)=\varphi_1\oplus a\varphi_2$, then
$$
U^*AU=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&a\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0&a\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&a^*\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$